# How to list the functions under the js namespace in ClojureScript REPL

Tags: dependencies, clojurescript

I try to use a JavaScript library `react-datagrid` with ClojureScript.

https://github.com/zippyui/react-datagrid
As shown in its tutorial, It should be used like this in JavaScript

```
    var React = require('react')
    var DataGrid = require('react-datagrid')
```

I just reference it in my `index.html` and I can't find its name in my ClojureScript code. So is it possible to list all the things under js namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You can try logging js/window to the browser console like so:

```
(.dir js/console js/window)
```

If the library has attached itself to the global namespace it should be there.